# Golang Appengine Project won't build

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have an appengine project using golang that I haven't touched in about a year.  I cannot get it to build now on the machine where it was building before.  I get the following error

> go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: parser: bad import "syscall" in src/golang.org/x/net/internal/nettest/rlimit_unix.go

I am running on OS X if that helps at all.  I am not a Golang expert, by any stretch, and my attempts to find anything even related to this have all turned up nothing.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

That usage is in net/internal.  You are probably importing net in your app engine project someplace, and thus doing the illegal import.

If you constrain your usage to net/http on an app engine project, you should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this:

> You are not permitted to import the syscall package in a Go App Engine
>   app for security reasons. Whatever file is importing it needs to be
>   changed to not do that, or be excluded from the build.

as per [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/k2U66zaKHjU)

So you might want to try [this workaround](https://github.com/oschwald/maxminddb-golang/commit/3d1a0574c315c71f3d8131ca13e4b4256061be09). If you are importing the 'os' module. It fixes [this](https://github.com/oschwald/maxminddb-golang/issues/11)

It would be helpful if you can post your code too.

Comment: I think you've nailed it -- Go and the appropriate way to use it (on any given environment, such as, App Engine) are changing fast, so code untouched and un-examined for a year bit-rotting... is far from surprising!

Comment: Ahh, OK - I will try that today.  Thanks!  There isn't a ton of code, but there is enough that I wasn't even sure where to start.

Comment: Hmm, I just checked the code, and I am not importing syscall anywhere.  The project is here: https://github.com/redmanatee/bodger-bowl/tree/master/src but I don't even know where to start.  I don't do a lot of go programming in my day to day, so I am struggling a bit here.

Comment: hmm, looks like it might be net/internal or something similar, based on some conversations with some other people.  I will look at that this evening.

Comment: Yep, like this guy: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/internal/socktest/sys_unix.go

Comment: I would also make sure that you have the latest app engine go sdk https://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/

Comment: Heh - first thing I did was update my appengine SDK, because of how long it had been.  I may end up rewriting the whole thing in Python, because that might be faster at this stage.

Comment: @aperkins noooooo :-)