# bad import "syscall" for cloud storage APIs

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am following the instructions on `https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/googlecloudstorageclient/download` to begin migrating some code from the, now deprecated, Files API to the new Cloud Storage API without success.

The steps I'm following are ...

I'm running appengine v1.9.23 which is later than the required appengine v1.8.1.

My $GOPATH is set, so I skip step #1.

I proceed to step #2:

`goapp get -u golang.org/x/oauth2`

`goapp get -u google.golang.org/cloud/storage`

I am not developing on a managed VM, so I skip step #3.

Now when I run the application, I get:

`go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: parser: bad import "syscall" in goapp/src/golang.org/x/net/internal/nettest/error_posix.go`

What am I doing wrong?

---

## Steps to reproduce

- Download an install the Google Appengine runtime, version 1.9.23 from https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/featured/ .  Follow the installation instructions documented on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads?hl=en
- Create an appengine project directory:

`% mkdir $HOME/myapp`

- Create a new `app.yaml` file as `~/myapp/app.yaml`.  Read the directions on the Google website for details: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig

I use a version that does not have the static resources:

```
application: myapp
version: alpha-001
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

- Create a location for the Go source files.

`% mkdir $HOME/myapp/go`

- Set your GOPATH to the location of your sources

`% export GOPATH=$HOME/myapp/go`

- Get the Go appengine example project: https://github.com/golang/example

`% goapp get github.com/golang/example/appengine-hello`

This command will download the example app to the first path entry in the GOPATH

- Install the Google Cloud Storage client libraries as directed in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/googlecloudstorageclient/download .  Reference the steps at the top of this question for more details.  Following the directions should result in you running 2 commands:

`% go get -u golang.org/x/oauth2`

`% go get -u google.golang.org/cloud/storage`

- Attempt to run your go application

`% goapp serve`

You will see the following compilation error (no stack trace):

`2015/12/23 10:37:07 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: parser: bad import "syscall" in go/src/golang.org/x/net/ipv6/control_unix.go`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang Appengine Project won't build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749342/golang-appengine-project-wont-build)

Comment: Within the context of the referenced question, my question could be stated: "Are Google's supplied instructions incorrect or am I doing something wrong?  The instructions appear to direct the user to use an library that requires `syscall` support with a platform that doesn't support it."

Comment: Is this error part of a larger stack trace? Could you provide more clear steps to how someone could reproduce this issue?

Comment: Nick - are you aware of a case where the instructions work for appengine-1.9.23?  The setting of the GOPATH in Google's instructions are ambiguous and could effect the result of the compilation, although I have not found a value that produces a correct result.  There is no stack trace for the error since it is a compilation error ("parse:").

Comment: I'm encountering the same thing and was about to ask this question myself. Have you found a resolution yet?

Comment: I do not have a resolution yet, but I am working through the issue with paid google support.

Comment: @AaronAlpar Solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by either of two scenarios:

1) Implicitly importing `syscall` by importing another package that uses it, as referenced in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749342/golang-appengine-project-wont-build).

2) Having your package source files in your `GOPATH` located in a directory at or below the same level as your project's app.yaml (eg. *app.yaml* in *~/go*, and packages sources in *~/go/gopath/src*). If a package like `x/net/internal/nettest` exists in your GOPATH the `syscall` import will be parsed by `goapp` at compile time and throw the compilation error.

Avoiding these two scenarios should be sufficient to prevent any `bad import "syscall"` errors or related compilation errors.

Comment: clear explanation, thanks! 
for 1) a typical culprit is the "net" package (so any custom TCP/UDP/Unix Socket code) because it imports syscall.
for 2) I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/48132666/3072751 provides a good solution if you are using vendor/.

Answer (score 0):

Reproduced the initial steps above and got a similar error, even if not explicitly mentioning syscall. However, running “goapp serve” in the appengine-hello directory results in no error at all.

Adam’s explanation at point 2 applies here correctly: one needs to place the app.yaml file at the right level in the directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

`sirupsen/logrus` references `syscall`.

They have an appengine tag specified, not to include syscall so it's usable in AppEngine, something like `go build -tags appengine` as per [issue 310](https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus/issues/310).

However I haven't yet succeeded including it in an AppEngine project so that this build param could be forwarded and specified somewhere so that it goes through. I'll come back to update if I manage.