# App Engine/Go: 'goapp serve' giving an error "Go application could not be built" error

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am trying to use Go with App Engine SDK for Go and when I run `goapp serve`, I get the following error in printed the browser after going to http://localhost:8080 (I get similar errors in the terminal):

> The Go application could not be built.
>
> (Executed command: C:\go_appengine\goroot\bin\go-app-builder.exe
>   -app_base C:\Projects\Go\Davilex -arch 6 -dynamic -goroot C:\go_appengine\goroot -nobuild_files ^^$ -unsafe -gopath
>   C:\Projects\Go -print_extras_hash controllers\form\form.go main.go
>   controllers\pages\pages.go models\form.go)
>
> 2016/01/20 22:10:42 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: parser: bad
>   import "syscall" in colorable_windows.go from GOPATH

Seems there is a *somewhat* similar question here a few days ago, with no resolve: [bad import "syscall" for cloud storage APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144642/bad-import-syscall-for-cloud-storage-apis)

At first I thought it was because I had both Python 2.7.x and 3.5.x installed and the the docs specifically say it will only work with v 2.7.x, so I uninstalled all 3.5.x references, removed the SDK and reinstalled it/unzipped/added its path to my PATH.

I can run `gcloud`, `goapp` and `go` all fine so everything should be set up correctly as far as I can tell, and just doing regular `go run main.go` runs fine and works, but I can't seem to be able to use `goapp serve` and I have no clue where to go about the error above.

**EDIT/SOLUTION**

I created a dummy project and just added this simple set of code into it:

```
package main

import "net/http"

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello world!"))
}
```

And the error seems to have gone away and everything works fine. So the problem must be occuring from either my code or my use of https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin package.

Hope that may help anyone with a similar problem. Try creating another project and see if it works. If it does, you now know where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I created a dummy project and just added this simple set of code into it:

```
package main

import "net/http"

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello world!"))
}
```

And the error seems to have gone away and everything works fine. So the problem must be occuring from either my code or my use of https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin package.

Hope that may help anyone with a similar problem. Try creating another project and see if it works. If it does, you now know where the issue is coming from.