# How do I make vendoring work with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am trying to introduce Go vendoring (storing dependencies in a folder called `vendor`) to an existing App Engine project. I have stored all dependencies in the vendor folder (using Godep as a helper) and it looks right, but running the application locally I get the following error:

`go-app-builder: Failed parsing input: package "golang.org/x/net/context" is imported from multiple locations: "/Users/erik/go/src/github.com/xyz/abc/vendor/golang.org/x/net/context" and "/Users/erik/go/src/golang.org/x/net/context"`

I believe the two locations should resolve to the same location, as Go applications should look in the `vendor` folder first. Is there a way to make Appengine understand that both dependencies are the same?

Comment: I've seen this issue in the past, it was usually resolved by making sure that all the `vendor` directories for the repositories that I was building were properly setup. What's the command you're running that results in this error?

Comment: The error was from dev_appserver.py. It seems reasonable to assume the vendor directories are not set up correctly, but do you have any clue how? It looks ok to me and our unittests run without any problem.

Comment: As I understand it, the `go-app-builder` tool works a bit differently from the standard go tooling in order to facilitate the App Engine specific builds, so that might be why you're seeing a discrepancy in the behavior. What version of the SDK are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this error using govendor instead of Godeps. The root cause appears to have been that vendored references with their own vendored references was not resolved correctly by Godeps.

The answer provided by Su-Au Hwang is also correct - you do have to keep app.yaml separate from your source.

Answer (score 9):

Your project directory (where app.yaml is) is probably in the GOPATH/src.
It shouldn't be.
The go-app-builder will take everything in the app.yaml folder (and below) and additionally merge your GOPATH into it, meaning now you have it twice.

The solution is to move app.yaml out of the GOPATH/src folder.
Additionally you'll find that `goapp test` works differently from `goapp serve` and `goapp deploy` when it comes to resolving dependencies.

So this is the solution I have been using (haven't used golang app engine in a while already) and it's the only setup I've found to work properly for all the `goapp` commands and for `govendor` to work properly (not sure about `godep`)

```
/GOPATH
├──/appengine
|   ├── app.yaml
|   └── aeloader.go
└──/src
    └── /MYPROJECT
         ├── main.go
         ├── /handler
         |    └── handler.go
         └── /vendor
```

details:

```
file: GOPATH/appengine/aeloader.go (NOTE the init function is necessary, probably a bug though)
package mypackage

import (
    _ "MYPROJECT"
)

func init() {
}
```

now run `goapp serve` and `goapp deploy` from `../GOPATH/appengine/` and `goapp test ./...` from `../GOPATH/src/MYPROJECT`

P.S. I find the global GOPATH thing silly and simply set my GOPATH to current project folder (in the example above `/GOPATH`) and check the whole thing into version control.

Comment: This is madness. Now it has to live *outside* GOPATH? Where does it end with the build idiosyncracies? Thank you, though. Seriously.

Comment: Nice answer. I created a simple app on GitHub to test this approach, it works: https://github.com/nikolay-turpitko/x-gae-dep

Answer (score 7):

I use a Makefile to move the `vendor` directory to a temporary `GOPATH`:

```
TMPGOPATH := $(shell mktemp -d)

deploy:
  mv vendor $(TMPGOPATH)/src
  GOPATH=$(TMPGOPATH) gcloud app deploy
  mv $(TMPGOPATH)/src vendor
```

I store this `Makefile` at the root of my service near the `vendor` directory and simply use `make deploy` to deploy manually or from the CI.

It works with Glide, Godeps or any tool that respects the Go vendor spec.

Please note, that you really need to move the `vendor` directory out of the build directory, otherwise the GoAppEngine compiler will try to build the vendor dependencies, potentially causing compile errors.

Comment: This is probably the best answer. You can keep your project not apengine specific and than just create a prebuild step like this and get your project in the exact format appengine wants

Comment: best approach/ answer

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue myself actually. The problem occurs when you're using the App Engine tools to build any package which imports something that is using vendoring, but the package you're trying to run doesn't have the import within it's vendor directory.

So, for example, if I'm trying to run package `foo`, which imports package `bar`, and both of which use the `github.com/gorilla/mux` library, if the `bar` repository has a `vendor/` directory that contains gorilla/mux, but the `foo` package doesn't have gorilla mux in it's `vendor/` directory, this error will occur.

The reason this happens is that the `bar` package will prioritize it's own `vendor` package over the one in the `GOPATH`, which is what `foo` will be using, causing a difference in the actual location of the imported paths.

The solution I found to this issue is to make sure that the `foo` directory is in the `GOPATH` and has the vendor directory properly installed. It's important to note that the `vendor/` convention only works from within the `GOPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Also got the same problem.
In the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/using-go-libraries) Google suggests the following:

> For best results, we recommend the following:
>
> - Create a separate directory in your app's directory for each service.
> - Each service's directory should contain the service's app.yaml file and one or more .go files.
> - Do not include any subdirectories in a service's directory.
> - Your GOPATH should specify a directory that is outside your app's directory and contain all the dependencies that your app imports.

But this messes up my project structure, which looks like this:

```
GOPATH/
└── src
    └── github.com
        └── username
            └── myproject
                ├── app.yaml
                ├── cmd
                │   └── myproject
                │       └── main.go
                ├── handlers
                │   └── api.go
                ├── mw
                │   ├── auth.go
                │   └── logger.go
                └── vendor
```

Where the `myproject` directory is a git project and the `vendor` folder contains all dependencies.
Running `gcloud deploy` from the `myproject` directory where `app.yaml` file lives doesn't work because first, `main.go` file is not in the same directory and second (from the same doc):

> you must be careful not to place your source code at or below your app's directory where the app.yaml file is located

What I ended up doing is building my own custom runtime instead, which turned out to be a very clean solution.
Simply generate the `Dockerfile` with the following command:

```
gcloud beta app gen-config --custom
```

Modify it, then specify `runtime: custom` in your `app.yaml` and deploy normally.
The trick here is of course that you're in control what gets copied where.
Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Dockerfile extending the generic Go image with application files for a
# single application.
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/golang

ENV GOPATH /go

# The files which are copied are specified in the .dockerignore file
COPY . /go/src/github.com/username/myproject/

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/username/myproject/

RUN go build -o dist/bin/myproject ./cmd/myproject

# All configuration parameters are passed through environment variables and specified in app.yaml
CMD ["/go/src/github.com/username/myproject/dist/bin/myproject"]
```

Don't forget that App Engine expects your application listening on port 8080. Check out [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build) doc for more details.